# Creating array inside array with foreach

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, dynamic-arrays

I just want to create array inside array. After creating this sub array i want to fill this with foreach.

What i want:

```
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Sıcak İçecekler] => Array
            (
                [foodId] => 1
                [foodName] => Food Name
                [foodPrice] => 15.25
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Et Döner] => Array
            (
                [foodId] => 2
                [foodName] => Another Food From another Cat
                [foodPrice] => 6.75
            )

    ))
```

My dynamic code

```
    foreach ($categoryList as $cat) {
    $food = [
        $cat["catName"] => [
            foreach (Food::foodsByCategory($cat["catId"], $db) as $food):
                "foodId" => $food["foodId"],
                "foodName" => $food["foodName"],
                "foodPrice" => $food["foodPrice"]
            endforeach;
        ]   
    ];

    array_push($foodsByCategory, $food);
}
```

> syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH), expecting ']'

Comment: Move your foreach outside to create his own array and then insert the array in `$cat["catName"]`.

Comment: HAHAHAHAHA that was soo easy man. :D thanks brother.

Comment: You should post this as an answer, so i can marked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik, PHP does not support this syntax (would be nice for a future version..), so you have to put the foreach outside and create a temporary array.

```
$cat["catName"] => [
    foreach (Food::foodsByCategory($cat["catId"], $db) as $food):
        "foodId" => $food["foodId"],
        "foodName" => $food["foodName"],
        "foodPrice" => $food["foodPrice"]
    endforeach;
]
```

becomes

```
$content = array();

// content creation
foreach (Food::foodsByCategory($cat["catId"], $db) as $food):
        content["foodId"] => $food["foodId"],
        content["foodName"] => $food["foodName"],
        content["foodPrice"] => $food["foodPrice"]
    endforeach;

// content insertion
$cat["catName"] = $content;
```

Actually, I find decoupling creation and insertion clearer as well.